# Qual o caminho para aprender análise sintática?

Tags: sintaxe

Eu tenho uma enorme dificuldade de aprender análise sintática, porque existem muitos termos que me confundem, e muitas vezes a explicação de um termo usa outros termos que eu não sei, e vira um labirinto.
Também parece que cada palavra numa mesma oração pode ter diferentes classificações, como "adjunto adnominal", "complemento nominal", etc...
Então, o que eu devo estudar primeiro, para ter conhecimento suficiente para entender análise sintática?

Comment: Li., como qualquer coisa complexa, se possível, é melhor aprender em ordem: https://www.todamateria.com.br/lingua-portuguesa/sintaxe/. Outra recomendação é anotar as classificações, e também ver exemplos e fazer exercícios — o TodaMatéria dá exemplos e exercícios. Se não quiseres aprender em ordem, será um labirinto, mas um labirinto nem perto de impossível. Se fores pelo labirinto, provavelmente terás de fazer isto: se não souberes X, pesquisa X; se lá aparecer Y, pesquisa Y, e assim por diante. Ou seja, é mais fácil aprender em ordem. Por sinal, aprender morfologoa antes pode ajudar.

Comment: Ver a mesma coisa em fontes diferentes também pode ajudar, mas entender também é do esforço teu, então, se vires o texto sobre adjunto adnominal e pensares "'tendi não, mas 'tá" ou "entendi mais ou menos", volta e lê de novo até se entender ou talvez ver outra fonte. Ademais, fazer exercícios é importante. Se não souberes fazer um sequer, não sabes sintaxe. Dos exemplos, não é apenas olhar e falar "'tá bom", mas tentar entender porque, por exemplo, "de ferro" foi classificado como adjunto adnominal no exemplo.

Comment: @Schilive Que tal escrever uma resposta baseada nos teus comentários? :)

Comment: @stafusa, para falar a verdade, eu nem achei que pergunta fosse ficar no ar, pela inexatidão.

Comment: @Schilive Sim, verdade, pode acabar sendo fechada.

Comment: @stafusa   Não ficaria melhor transferir a pergunta para META?

Comment: Boa pergunta, @Centaurus. Acho que não, já que o Meta é para discutir o site. O que tem que ser decidido é se a pergunta se encaixa em "Problems encountered by people learning Portuguese" e, portanto, on-topic — se não for, daí é o caso de fechar e recomendar fazer a mesma pergunta no chat. Uma opção intermediária é transformar a questão em wiki. Num primeiro momento vou esperar por flags e mais comentários. O que você acha?

Comment: @stafusa  Eu acho que "análise sintática" não é uma questão específica de língua portuguesa.  Ela é feita em Inglês, francês, etc, com algumas diferenças.  Quando eu sugeri o META, seria para discutir a validade da pergunta.  Mas sua sugestão de discutir em chat talvez seja a melhor.

Comment: @Centaurus e Stafusa, o site https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ diz que perguntas subjetivas devem ser fechadas. O Priberam define *subjetivo* como "Que depende de opiniões pessoais ou do indivíduo". Indivíduos genéricos diferentes têm amiúde facilidades diferentes para modos diferentes de aprender, desd'a linguagem da fonte até visão dela expressa. >>

Comment: @stafusa, >> Então, o conjunto de ações que ajudariam uma pessoa a aprender análise sintática se difere do que ajudariam outrem tal que se lhe há uma possível resposta suficientemente abrangente e válida para o site, o conhecimento necessário para fazê-la seria tanto que seria irrazoável pedi-lo de alguém do site. Logo, seria irrazoável ter uma pergunta suficientemente objetiva. Ergo, a resposta é subjetiva, senão irrazoavelmente. Pessoalmente, só acho matéria por razão discutível se há ou não uma resposta resposta suficientemente abrangente e para o site válida. >>

Comment: >> Isso é conforme a diferença dos conjuntos supraditos, o que é assaz grande para haver uma resposta assim. P.ex.: se a reposta oferecer fontes, é razoabilíssimo pensar que nenhuma delas servirá para vários, porquanto uma resposta não se direciona apenas a quem perguntou, mas, outrossim, àqueles genéricos que tem essa pergunta. Se a resposta oferecer técnicas, é ainda mais razoável o mesmo; ademais, há tantas técnicas e métodos que um conhecimento geral delas seria uma irrazoável pedição dalguém o site. Note-se que uma qualidade cara de um professor é sua habilidade adaptativa com quem ensina

Comment: Li, nós aqui respondemos a perguntas específicas. Por exemplo, poderíamos explicar a classificação duma oração concreta ou a diferença entre adjunto nominal e complemento nominal, ou explicar um caso concreto: porque é que em *ela tem confiança no irmão*, *no irmão* é complemento nominal e não adjunto nominal. Portanto, quando tiveres uma dúvida concreta, não hesites; pergunta e nós tentaremos dar uma resposta concreta. Agora esta tua pergunta é muito abrangente. Uma razão para fechar uma pergunta é ela ser tão abrangente que a resposta poderia dar um livro. Por isso votei para fechar.